# Json Parsing Android in Listview

Tags: android, json, parsing, android-listview, pubnub

I am working on application in which i am getting list of my history using pubnub which contains message and time token. The Original Json string is given below:

```
[[{"message":"hdjcjcjjckckckckvkckckck","timetoken":14151866297757284},{"message":"ufjfjfjcjfjchfjdhwjroritkgjcj","timetoken":14151869212145693},{"message":"qMobile","timetoken":14152601234812083}],14151866297757284,14152601234812083]
```

After using following method i have get the following Json String in JSONObject c.

```
{"message":"hdjcjcjjckckckckvkckckck","timetoken":14151866297757284}


pubnub.history(channel, true, 100, new Callback() {
                            @Override
                            public void successCallback(String channel,
                                                        Object message) {
                                notifyUser("HISTORY : " + message);

                              Log.i("Received msg : ", message.toString());  //<==== receiving Messages here


                              try {

                                JSONArray jsonObj = new JSONArray(message.toString()); 
                                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(jsonObj.get(0).toString());
                                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {

                                    JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                                    String messageString=c.getString("message");
                                    String timeString=c.getString("timetoken");
                                    String abc = timeString;

                                }

                            }
```

Now i just want to display my each Json Object in ListView like this

message:dsfdsvsfvdfvfdvdvgd
timetoken:14132423414141
message:dsfwfwefwedcsfsw
timetoken:21431353153252
message:dthfjtyhnfgvb
timetoken:68624526246

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Then implement ListAdapter and show it.

Comment: @pratt Thanks for your reply. Can you please provide some code snippet for this? Because i was not getting ListAdapter technique for this.

Comment: Why you are not Gson api.. Try it it is very easy

Comment: check this link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/    this may help you..

Comment: @Chowdary102 I have clicked in your link but it is not allowing me to download code. Please if you have downloaded copy then please let me know here

Answer (score 1):

Declare one ArrayList of hashmap like below:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> data= new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
HashMap<String,String> jsonData;
private EfficientAdapter adapter;

//In your onCreate() method, just initialize your adapter.
adapter = new EfficientAdapter(this);
```

Now, inside this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonData=new HashMap<String,String>();
    JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

    String messageString=c.getString("message");
    String timeString=c.getString("timetoken");
    String abc = timeString;

    jsonData.put("message",messageString);
    jsonData.put("timeStamp",timeString);

    data.add(jsonData);
}

YOURLISTVIEW.setAdapter(adapter);
```

//List Adapter code:

```
private class EfficientAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        private Context context;

        public EfficientAdapter(Context context) {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            final ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.YOUR LAYOUT FILE TO SHOW MESSAGE AND TIME, null);
                //Just create one xml in layout folder and give that layout file name like R.layout.list_item.
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.txtMessage = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMessage);
                holder.txtTimestamp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtTimestamp);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            holder.txtMessage.setText(data.get(position).get("message"));
            holder.txtTimestamp.setText(data.get(position).get("timeStamp"));

            convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    //your list click event here
                }
            });

            return convertView;
        }

        class ViewHolder {
            TextView txtMessage;
            TextView txtTimestamp;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks @pratt for your detailed reply. I am using using above code snippet. I just need to know about following code:  for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    jsonData=new HashMap<String,String>();
    JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
    String messageString=c.getString("message");
    String timeString=c.getString("timetoken");
    jsonData.put("message",messageString);
    jsonData.put("timeStamp",timeString);
    data.add(jsonData);}
YOURLISTVIEW.setAdapter(adapter); //Where we are updating adapter value, from above code we just make it but not passing values in it.

Comment: you will get it, we are adding all your json data in array named "data" so you will get that data in Adapter also, create Adapter class with your existing Activity not like 2nd class.

Answer (score 0):

A better option is to use GSON, it will save your time in the future with json parsing.

1. Download gson and add it to your project http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.google.code.gson%7Cgson%7C2.3%7Cjar
2. Paste your json - http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/, and make a java class representation.
3. Use your json String (or Reader), your created class (in point 2.) and get a object that has all the values that the json has -

   Gson gson = new Gson();
   yourObject = gson.fromJson(yourJsonString, yourObject.class);

   4. And then use this object inside your adapter. For example - message = yourObject.get(position).getMessage();